# How to get props at the first rendering

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a container component in which I get the ID and drop this ID into the function and the request goes, in principle, the props should come right away, but they are undefined. But when you re-enter the same component, the necessary props are shown.

Explain how to make props appear on the first render?

```js
class View extends React.Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    let id = this.props.match.params.id;
    this.props.GetProjData(id);
  }

  render() {
    return <ProjView {...this.props}></ProjView>;
  }
}

let mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      NameProj: state.project.OneProject.NameProj,
      Text: state.project.OneProject.Text,
      target: state.project.OneProject.target,
      startdate: state.project.OneProject.startdate,
      enddate: state.project.OneProject.enddate
    },
    error: state.settings.error,
    loading: state.settings.loading
  };
};
```

My request

```js
export const GetProjData = data => async (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  { getFirestore }
) => {
  const firestore=getFirestore()
  try {
    await firestore
    .collection("Projects")
    .where("idProject", "==", data)
    .get().then(snap => {
      snap.forEach(doc => {
       let project=doc.data()
        console.log(doc.data());
        dispatch({type:getOne,project})
      });
    })

 
  } catch (err) {}
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Which props is undefined? the `react-router` one or the `redux` one?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi As I understand it, I'm sending data to componentDidMount, and the component is already rendered, it does not wait for props

Comment: Yes, `componentDidMount` is called after the first render. If you need props before the first render do it in  the constructor. But this shouldn't have anything to do with them being undefined. If your props are undefined, it has to do with the parent component, not this one.

Comment: Also, explain what you mean by "reenter" the component. If the component is unmounted and remounted, the original component will have no effect on the newly mounted one. Is it hidden from view or not rendered at all?

Comment: @BrianThompson And how i do this?Just move my code in to constructor?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't really think thats the root of the problem here. Is `GetProjData` fetching your `initialValues` data?

Comment: @BrianThompson I have projects in which data is stored, I want to look at this data, when I go in for the first time it is empty, and when I re-enter the data. The data should appear in the fields

Comment: @BrianThompson check my  GetProjData

Comment: @BrianThompson I get data from the server and make an object out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the flow of your app correctly, you need to account for the renders between when you request your project data and when you receive the project data.

```js
class View extends React.Component {
  // constructor fires first so we might as well move it here
  constructor(props) {
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    props.GetProjData(id);
  }

  render() {
    // Your component will rerender before receiving the new data.
    // We block the component from mounting so that initialValues 
    // gets set only when we have the data needed
    if (this.props.initialValues && this.props.initialValues.NameProj) {
      // A better way to do this would be to listen to a loading variable 
      // that gets updated when your request finishes
      return <ProjView {...this.props} />;
    }
    return null; // or loading graphic
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow,I didn’t even think about it. Thanks!